# filter and conditional sort at same time in isar db for flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-isar

Previously i used flutter sqflite package to build this kind of query where the user can search by name and also sort by balance or most recent (createdAt/updated at) like this

```dart
Future<List<CustomerModel>> fetchAllCustomer(String query, int sortID) async {
    try {
      final db = await DatabaseServices().database;
      String orderByClause = '';
      switch (sortID) {
        case 0:
          orderByClause = 'ORDER BY updated_at DESC';
          break;
        case 1:
          orderByClause = 'ORDER BY CASE WHEN balance = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, balance DESC';
          break;
        case 2:
          orderByClause = 'ORDER BY LOWER(name) ASC';
          break;
        case 3:
          orderByClause = 'ORDER BY updated_at ASC';

          break;

        case 4:
          orderByClause = 'ORDER BY CASE WHEN balance = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, balance ASC';
          break;
        default:
          orderByClause = 'ORDER BY updated_at DESC';
      }

      final coss = await db.rawQuery('''
      SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE type = 0 AND branch_id = $branchID AND name LIKE "%$query%" $orderByClause
''');

      return coss.map((e) => CustomerModel.fromMap(e)).toList();
    } catch (e, st) {
      LoggerManager.red('fetchAllCustomer err $e $st');
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }
```

for isar how can I achieve this if I have all the same fields for the isar db collection?

Comment: Do not add tag information in the title. Especially, do NOT use square brackets. The tag system here works extremely well and does not need help, and square brackets in the titles are used to indicate [closed] or [duplicate] posts. For more information, see [ask] and [Should questions include "tags" in the title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).